# Vanilla JavaScript - Unbind

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which looks for a click event for all td elements:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td'), function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var clicked = [];
        clicked.push(event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-a'));
        clicked.push(event.target.getAttribute('data-b'));
        this.callEvent(clicked, event.target);
    }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));
```

Then I have a basic if else statement that checks the data attrs. It appears like the click function is staying bound as in the if statement I have logged to the console which condition is true.
After the very first run through, the true condition only runs, then if the next run through, the false runs, the true does also.. and then each time after, the conditions runs for each of the previous clicks.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to somehow unbind the click function each time?

Comment: Have you checked what `this` is when you're trying to run `this.callEvent`? I don't like the look of those `.bind(this)` bits...

Comment: Event handlers remaing attached until you remove them (e.g., with `removeEventListener`) or the element is destroyed. You seem to be running this code repeatedly; that's usually not a good idea (and will, with your code, result in your having the handlers attached multiple times). Normally you'd want to hook them up **once** and then have them do (or not do) what they do in response to the information they find when run.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: They're fine, `this` will be whatever `this` is when that code is run.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder So if I don't repeatedly call the function, the events won't remain attached?
Would this mean I wouldn't need to use `removeEventListener`, or would I need to anyway?

Comment: It is working now, thanks again for all your help. I just removed the click handler out from a function that gets repeatedly called and it works a charm :)

Comment: @LeMoi please post the answer and mark it as resolved